# Part of list not rendered

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I'm having a problem with layout rendering. I have some experience in `C#` but i never encountered something like this before.

I'm building an video messaging application, when a conversation starts an new window is opened and the list and background are set on `Collapsed`.
At the end of an conversation the new window closes and the list and background are set back to Visible.

when that happens i get this:
[image]
My list is build with StackPanel and UserControl, when i scroll the list the rendering is fine again.

I did some research on Google about objects that aren't rendered on the UI and found that you can use `InvalidateVisual` to force the UI to be rendered again, but this doesn't seem to be working in my application. I call this method at the end of every conversation, after making the list and background Visible.

What are some ways to make sure the UI gets rendered correctly?
Thanks.

**Update 1:**

I've added this piece of code to my UserControl.

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
   InvalidateVisual();
   base.OnRender(drawingContext);
}
```

But is this the way to go? I've already seen that method is called over and over in loop when i do it this way, but i doesn't seem to affect the performance on the devices i test on.

**Update 2:**

After some more intensive test i found that the code i added in Update 1 does have a great impact on the performance of the application, so this is not going to work for me.

**Update 3:**

Now I've created an delay before `InvalidateVisual` is called, using a `Timer`. Is set the Timer to 500 milliseconds before calling `InvalidateVisual`, this forces the layout to render again. By the time my second window is closed the layout will be updated an second time. Here is my code

```
Timer t = new Timer(500);
t.AutoReset = false;
t.Elapsed += (s, ee) =>
{
   ((Timer)s).Stop();
   ((Timer)s).Dispose();
   InvalidateVisual();
};
t.Start();
```

After a quick test it seems to work, but i need to test it more intensely to make sure. Any other suggestions are still welcome.

**Update 4:**

After testing my solution in update 3, i found out this is not going to work.
@Sheridan: My application doesn't need re sizing, it is an full screen application. This is the code i wrote to create the list:

This the XAML code

```
<TabItem x:Name="TabHistory" Header="Geschiedenis">
  <sys:FixedScrollViewer VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     PanningMode="VerticalOnly" 
                     Margin="0,0,0,7"
                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel x:Name="CallLogList" />
  </sys:FixedScrollViewer>
</TabItem>
```

And this is the code that fills it.

```
private void OnRosterUpdate(object sender, RosterUpdateEventArgs e) 
{
  if (MessageWindow.IsOpen) MessageWindow.Close();
  Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
  {
     if (e.Action == RosterAction.ADD)
     {
        RosterContact button = new RosterContact(e.Item);
        button.Call += StartCall_Callback;
        button.ShowInfo += Info_Callback;
        button.HideInfo += button_HideInfo;
        roster.Children.Add(button);
     }
     else if (e.Action == RosterAction.REMOVE)
     {
        foreach (RosterContact item in roster.Children)
        {
           if (item.UserData.Peer == e.Item.Peer)
           {
              roster.Children.Remove(item);
              break;
           }
        }
     }
  });
}
```

RosterContact is of type UserControl.

Comment: try using this.Invalidate() after you scroll

Comment: When i scroll even a little, rendering goes OK again. So i think its really in making it Collapse and then making it Visible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this anything to do with `InvalidateVisual`... in WPF, we don't need to manually refresh the UI... when written properly, WPF takes care of refreshing the UI.

Unfortunately, you didn't show any code so it's hard to tell for sure, but whenever I hear/read about the `StackPanel` and rendering problems, it normally means the same thing... don't use `StackPanel`s for UI layout!! They *don't* resize their contents. Try replacing them with `Grid`s and your problem *might* just be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I searched allot and found nothing on this. So i made up my own way make sure the list does not disappear on me. It may be a little dirty but i could not come with anything else. Of course are suggestions still welcome when another way is found.

The way i do it now is by creating a full white screen on the screen. I do that like this, first i created a fullscreen Grid on in my form and gave it an white background.

```
<Grid Background="White" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="gridWhite" />
```

I also created a function that makes the white screen Visible and Collapses it after a second.

```
private void ShowWhiteScreen()
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        gridWhite.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        Timer t = new Timer(1000);
        t.AutoReset = false;
        t.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
        {
            ((Timer)s).Stop();
            ((Timer)s).Dispose();
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                gridWhite.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            });
        };
        t.Start();
    });
}
```

I tested this by calling the test tablet from another tablet and after the conversation my bug didn't appear again. I did the test 5 times on both the devices and same result every time.